# JavaDB(Derby) - Connection refused using Network Server Controller in LAN

Tags: networking, localhost, derby, javadb

I'm new to java networking. My scenario here is 2 client computers are connecting to a server hosted in LAN. So I use NetworkServerControl API to start the host:

```
private static void startServer(){
    try{
        NetworkServerControl nsc = new NetworkServerControl(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 1527);
        nsc.start(null);
    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Start network error : " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

My questions are:
1) Is localhost accessible by computers in LAN?
- If yes, I tried to use ij to connect derby database in the server but it wrote connection refused. Anything I missed out?

```
ij: CONNECT 'jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/c:/app_db/' user 'xxx' password 'xxx';
```

- If no, what is the common approach should be used? Please guide me the right track.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To access your Derby database from other machines on the network, you need to change "localhost" to a different value. You can give the DNS name of your machine, or the public IP address of your machine.

Note that you have to make this change both on the Derby server and on each of the client URLs.

You should be able to use netstat -a to confirm the effects of your changes on the server.